# Spring Boot + Spring Data JPA query from java.util.Date type using only the month

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm using `Spring Boot 1.4.0` with `Spring Data JPA 1.10.2`, and I find myself in an impasse to create a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myDatabase
WHERE
MONTH(nascimento) = '11';
```

My goal is list all birthdays of the current month, of a field with sql format `year-month-day`.

In my `@Entity`, I store a `java.util.Date` type attribute, named **nascimento**.

```
@Entity
public class Cliente {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @NotEmpty
    private String nome;

    @NotNull
    private Date nascimento;

    // Get/Set...
}
```

In my `@Repository` I use the Spring Data `CrudRepository` interface.

```
@Repository
public interface ClienteRepository extends CrudRepository<Cliente, Integer> {
    // Methods...
}
```

Is there any way to perform a query using only the month on attribute of java Date type?

I would like to create an interoperable query between relational DBMS using the [Query methods](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods) supported by Spring Data framework.

Currently I solve this problem with this approach (but I believe it is not appropriate for all Databases):

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Cliente WHERE MONTH(nascimento) like ?1", nativeQuery = true)
Iterable<Cliente> findAllByNascimentoLike(String Month);
```

To think of the solution, and if necessary use the month and day?
Thanks for trying to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [JPA Query Expressions](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/expression) this language is independent of the database. The JPA query expresion it would be similar to your native Query ([you may use function MONTH](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_2_2/jpa/jpql_functions.html)):

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM Cliente u WHERE MONTH(u.nascimento) = ?1")
Iterable<Cliente> findAllByNascimentoLike(Integer month);
```

Comment: If Month is supported

Comment: Thanks @pau-chorro, i try this, works great, by the `MONTH()` temporal functions needs a `Integer` attribute.  And if in a case of database does not offer support of functions for use with temporal values?

Comment: Try with `Select u from Cliente u where SUBSTRING(u.nascimiento, 6, 7) = ?1`