# Creating a custom spring JPA query with Date attribute

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, date, jpa

This is my first Java Spring project ever. I'm using PostgreSQL to store a `WorkedDay` entity as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class WorkedDay {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date weekDay;

    @Column
    private Long employeeId;

    @ManyToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "employeeId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Employee employee;

    @OneToMany
    private List<WorkedHours> workedHours = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

All "WorkedDays" are stored in a PostgreSQL table using a `WorkedDayRepository` class that extends `CrudRepository`. I'm also creating a report service which should return a list of `WorkedDays` in a given month.

```
public class WorkedDayRepositoryImpl implements WorkedDayRepositoryCustom {

    public List<WorkedDay> getReportByMonthValue(int monthValue) {
        //service code implementation here
    }
}
```

I'm currently facing problems creating this custom query, since I need to retrieve from the table all `Date weekDay` attributes with a specific month, passed as argument.

I'm inexperienced with Spring JPA. Is there a better(or simpler) way to do this? I tried to use Specifications and Querydsl but failed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot + Spring Data JPA query from java.util.Date type using only the month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38903135/spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-query-from-java-util-date-type-using-only-the-mont)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
@Repository
public interface WorkedDayRepository extends CrudRepository<WorkedDay> {

   List<WorkedDay> findByWeekDay_Month(int month)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try `@Query` in combination with the `MONTH` Function.

```
@Repository
public interface WorkedDayRepository extends CrudRepository<WorkedDay> {

   @Query("select w from WorkedDay w where MONTH(w.weekDay) = ?1")
   List<WorkedDay> findByWeekDay(int month)

}
```

Keep in mind that not all databases might support MONTH(). Otherwise you could work with `SUBSTRING(w.weekDay,6,7)`